# I have to delete my deleted call logs permanently

Tags: delete, call-history

I tried many apps like complete wipe,but I am unable to delete my deleted call logs permanently,whenever I start recovery program they show my deleted call logs can u please suggest how to permanently delete call logs which cannot ne recovered ASAP..Please help Stucked very badly..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rooted device, you can delete your call logs by using any file explorer with root access and modify this file: **/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db**

Comment: A File explorer can only take you to that file, it won't (usually) open the `.db` file for you. So how exactly should this file be opened, what needs to be modified, please detail. // You possibly got this info from other source, so do mention it here.

Comment: @Firelord ah yes my bad. Here's the source http://www.droidforums.net/threads/call-log-location.147841/

Comment: Sorry!, but we try to use off-site resources only as a source not as a dependency which means if the link fails our answers would still remain useful to people. Please consider adding the relevant info into the answer.